# Wrong query entered into PROLOG?

Tags: prolog

quick question.

Whenever I make a mistake in the Prolog query (compilation part)

i.e I attempt to run a file but I forget to add a dot at the end"

```
1 ?- [lecture1]
|    
|    
|
```

Whenever I press enter (or type in anything then press enter) I just keep getting these

```
|
```

How the hell do I get out of this and go in to

```
2 ?-
```

I'm fairly new at Prolog and this is starting to annoy me a bit (I restart Prolog to get rid of this!).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a dot:

```
?- [lecture1]
|    
|    
|    
|   . 
% lecture1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.
```

the idea is that you can write your queries in multiple lines.

You can also press `Ctl-D` and then `a` for abort if you want to cancel it completely (you can also do that while it's running)

Answer (score 1):

It's just something visual from the toplevel. The input remains as-is when you press enter in the middle of a query, so if you had written `[lecture1]` and then enter you can just add the missing dot.

In your example, you can just press `.` and then `<enter>`, to load the file.

In general, pressing `.` and then `<enter>` will either execute the goal or just get a complain by the prolog system and the you are again free to execute any goal...